# Sending a single email message with different content for each recipient (using cc field)

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

Before you dismiss this question because it "makes no sense" and "it's impossible" please hear me out:

**The issue:**

We implement a tracking pixel (i downloadable GIF file with a unique URL) in each email that we send using our system, this helps us track opening of email messages. The problem with this is, that when we cc a few recipients the tracking pixel is downloaded and we can not detect **who** has opened this email, since all emails are CC'ed the content must be the same.

**Possible solution:**

If the SMTP server were to control injecting the tracking pixel, the SMTP can change the message body from recipient to recipient by posting each recipient with a different URL, pretending that all recipients received the same message.

**However**, using a public SMTP server (e.g. Google's SMTP) this does not seem possible, yet there are companies ([AirMail](http://airmailapp.com/) for example) that still are able to do this, sending different content (different tracking URL per recipient in a cc message). When I check the email headers they seems to have been sent from googles SMTP server (clients account uses a gmail.com account). How is this possible?

Comment: Did you get any clue or solution?

Comment: Did you get solution? or solution pertains to SMPT level?

Answer (score 0):

They are creating a unique message for each individual. Nothing really magical. Usually some type of mail merge.

Comment: This is not a option, since the message shows all the recipients have received the same message, again, unless its manipulated at the SMTP level

Comment: Any luck solving this one? I'm facing similar problem.

Comment: You would do something like this for an img src:
/myimage.gif?id=1234
And, you would have a handler at the web server level grab the id, and record it.

/1234.gif  where 1234 is the id. The image doesn't actually exist, you just have a handler serve up the beacon image, and record the 1234 

Likewise, you could also do something like this: