# Adding the recipient email address to the email body

Tags: c#, email

I'm using C# code with basic System.Net.Mail.**SmtpClient** to send email to recipients.

In the email's body, I need to add the email address for each recipient, Is there is a way to do so in one email to multiple recipients?

```
//basic settings    
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";

//relevent part
msgClient.To.Add(user1@hotmail.com);
msgClient.To.Add(user2@hotmail.com);
msgClient.To.Add(user3@hotmail.com);
mail.Body = "I need to put here the customer's Email Address without sending multiple emails";

client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: `add the email address for each recipient` what do you mean by this ? The current email ? or something else ?

Comment: The current email, user1@hotmail.com will receive user1@hotmail.com in the body, user2@hotmail.com should receive user2@hotmail.com and so on..

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible due to SMTP protocol limitations if you want to do this, you probably should send your emails one by one. nonetheless, it is best if you change the format of your emails so you don't need to include such data in the message body.

---

ps: `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClien` is deprecated use [mailkit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead, the APIs are the same, so you don't need to change your code, you just need to install it via NuGet and then change the reference from `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClien` to `MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient`

Comment: Basically, I need to add to the email's body a link contains the user's email as parameter. Although, I still am designing the structure of the link, if to send the email or some integer ID.
I'm trying to avoid using 3rd party libraries, are you sure mailkit has this option? Do you maybe have an example?

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480102/sending-a-single-email-message-with-different-content-for-each-recipient-using , however, public smtp servers dont let it. 2: you can use mailkit with confidence, it is suggested by MS it self, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8 , under remarks section

Comment: I tried to find example code with mailkit which solved my problem but google has no answers yet.